# Trying to recursively render comments ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, rails-api

Here is my data structure for my comments. I think I have the wrong data structure to render comments recursively. Please advise. I can get single comments and one reply, but not an unknown amount of replys.

```
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "content": "This is so great!",
      "recipe_id": 1,
      "commentable_id": 1,
      "commentable_type": "Recipe",
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-09-08T00:16:55.296Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-09-08T00:16:55.296Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "content": "This is another one",
      "recipe_id": 1,
      "commentable_id": 1,
      "commentable_type": "Comment",
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-09-08T00:16:55.323Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-09-08T00:16:55.323Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "content": "This is another one",
      "recipe_id": 1,
      "commentable_id": 2,
      "commentable_type": "Comment",
      "user_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-09-08T00:16:55.332Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-09-08T00:16:55.332Z"
    },
```

Comment: Are the objects with ID 2 and ID 3 children to the object with ID 1? That is, for objects with `commentable_type == 'Comment'`, `commentable_id` refers to a comment ID?

Comment: @AKX object with ID 2 is a child of ID 1 and ID 3 is a child of ID2.  Commentable_id refers to the comment id that is being commented on. Hope that clears it up a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data structure you get from your API is set in stone, you can "inflate" a tree of comments from that flat data. I've elided the user-id and date information below to keep things shorter.

The idea is that `<CommentBoxes>` renders a list of comments as `<CommentBox>` components; the full list of comments is passed around to make sure `<CommentBox>` can filter through it to find child comments, if any, for the comment it's rendering.

```js
const commentData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    content: "This is so great!",
    recipe_id: 1,
    commentable_id: 1,
    commentable_type: "Recipe",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    content: "This is another one",
    recipe_id: 1,
    commentable_id: 1,
    commentable_type: "Comment",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    content: "This is another one",
    recipe_id: 1,
    commentable_id: 2,
    commentable_type: "Comment",
  },
];

const CommentBox = ({ comment, allComments }) => {
  const children = allComments.filter(
    (c) => c.commentable_type === "Comment" && c.commentable_id === comment.id
  );
  return (
    <li>
      {comment.content}
      {children ? <CommentBoxes comments={children} allComments={allComments} /> : null}
    </li>
  );
};

const CommentBoxes = ({ comments, allComments }) => (
  <ul>
    {comments.map((c) => (
      <CommentBox comment={c} allComments={allComments} key={c.id} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const App = () => {
  const rootComments = commentData.filter((c) => c.commentable_type === "Recipe");
  return <CommentBoxes comments={rootComments} allComments={commentData} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! As a react noobie this was really helpful explanation. I have tested it out in my application and it works great! It was wonderful to see the thought process of how to solve similar challenges like this in the future.

Comment: do you happen to know how I could go about rendering a reply with each comment and then submitting that reply?

I have tried to implement it and it just infinitely loops and crashes. Many Thanks.

Comment: How about having a `<CommentBox>` also render a `<ReplyBox>` (that doesn't itself render any child `CommentBox`es or `CommentBoxes`es?

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding the concept and am sorry if I did not follow your advice correctly. I added 
```
<input type="text" value={reply} onChange={updateReply}></input> <button>Reply</button>
```
to the CommentBox <li> and it will not let me input any data into the text box for a reply.

Comment: Without knowing what `reply` and `updateReply` are, that doesn't help much... Please ask another question with your full revised code, and maybe link it here so I can take a look.

Comment: thank you for your continued guidance and support. Here is the link. stackoverflow.com/q/63817009/14211989

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

You could store replies as children of comments:

```
{
  id: 3,
  content: "this is a comment",
  replies: [
    {
      id: 1,
      content: "This is a reply"
    }
]
```

Or you could store replies at the same level as comments. If you choose this method you will need a reply_to property, which should reference a comment id if it is a reply, or null (or better yet just unset) if it is a direct comment and not a reply.

Which method you choose will depend on the rest of your data structure and app behaviour.